# Huber's derivation of asymptotic properties of M-estimator (Robust Statistics)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, robust-statistics

Below are snippets of Chapter 3 of Huber's "Robust Statistics. They are needed to derive the asymptotic normality of M-estimator. However, I am concerning the step going from  (2.17) to (2.18) i.e. how did he get
$$ 
P\{T_n^{*}<t)=P\Big\{\sum \psi(x_i;t)\leq 0\Big\}
$$
The author mentioned something about the continuity of $t$ and I can sort of see it graphically (if the $\sum \psi(x_i;t)$ is a continuous random variable for example) but
I cannot use it to fill in the missing detail formally.

---

[image]

Comment: $\mathsf{P}(T_n^*=t)=\mathsf{P}(T_n^{**}=t)=0$

Comment: @d.k.o.  What if they are not continuous random variables?

Comment: It seems that the author means that $t$ is a continuity point of the distribution of $T_n^*$ (and $T_n^{**}$). Otherwise, the equalities won't hold.